# Match words with num/dash/underscore

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with writing correct RegExp, which matches words with and without numbers/dashes/underscore
Correct words:

```
stackoverflow
stackoverfloW1
stack-overflow
stack_overflow1
```

etc.
I've came up with this one: `\w+(-\w+)+([A-Za-z0-9_\-])`, but it matches only words with dash, so `stack-overflow` works, but not `stackoverflow`

Comment: Why not `([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)` ? See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/fD9rC7/1).

Comment: Ok I swear I've tried this one before, as it was my first guess, but now it works. Magic! :D Unfortunately I can't mark comment as answer, feel free to post it as answer and I will rep you. Thanks!

Comment: @Raston: Doesn't [`\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/wD9iU6/3) work better for you? `[-_a-zA-Z0-9]+` will match `_stack` and `stack_` and `stack___--`.

Comment: Well, depending on the language and Unicode requirements the regex can further be improved.

Comment: @stribizhev simplier works fine, client is ok with that. But +1 for more complicated regexp, may be needed when client changes mind ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, here an answer as well:

```
([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)
# will match dash, underscore, a-z, A-Z an numbers
```

See the [mentionned regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/fD9rC7/1). However, look into @stribizhev's comment as well as he is far more experienced than I am (considering his reputation he's here all the time...).

Comment: FYI: number of points is not an indicator of overall experience and regex knowledge level.

Comment: @stribizhev This might be true but in your case - looking at the different regex answers you have given so far - one can assume a certain level of experience - at least in this field ;-)

Comment: :) I just mean people with 700 points of reputation can also be skillful at regex :)